# Range of all elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

Suppose I have a 1d array `a` where from each element I would like to have a range of which the size is stored in `ranges`:

```
a = np.array([10,9,12])
ranges = np.array([2,4,3])
```

The desired output would be:

```
np.array([10,11,9,10,11,12,12,13,14])
```

I could of course use a `for` loop, but I prefer a  fully vectorized approach. `np.repeat` allows one to repeat the elements in `a` a number of times by setting `repeats=`, but I am not aware of a similar `numpy` function particularly dealing with the problem above.

Comment: This seems to be enough of a niche occurrence that I can imagine that no specific functionality exists for this use case in NumPy. `hstack` with a list comprehension involving `arange` seems to be the most straightforward solution.

Comment: Are you using this often (e.g., in a tight loop), that you prefer a vectorized approach? For a one-off (or few times usage), any solution that works will be fine and not hamper performance.

Comment: Hmm, in principle all the information needed is ```np.repeat(a, ranges)```, as it will produce ```array([10, 10,  9,  9,  9,  9, 12, 12, 12])``` . I am just a bit stuck on how to convert the consecutive repeats to ranges

Comment: It is certainly something I would need recurrently, but perhaps you're right a loop is still good enough. I am just always trying to avoid as much as possiblethem for code I'll over and over. Hence the question asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pandas` it could be easier:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series(np.repeat(a, ranges))
>>> x + x.groupby(x).cumcount()
0    10
1    11
2     9
3    10
4    11
5    12
6    12
7    13
8    14
dtype: int64
>>>
```

If you want a numpy array:

```
>>> x.add(x.groupby(x).cumcount()).to_numpy()
array([10, 11,  9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14], dtype=int64)
>>>
```

Comment: Certainly not a bad solution. I wonder how it compares to list comprehension in terms of timing

Comment: @pr94 This would be much quicker than list comprehension.

Comment: @pr94 Numpy is developed with C, list comprehensions are slow, so Using this might be hundreds of times faster

Comment: Yes I know. I thought perhaps the use of pandas would slow down a bit

Comment: @pr94 Pandas backend is in Numpy, so it's the same speed as numpy

Comment: You'll find that user1740577's solution is the fastest, then mine, then this solution. *But*, this is for the very small input example array from the question, where Python's list comprehensions can be very fast. You'll need arrays of 1000s of elements to really see which version is fastest.

Comment: @9769953 Yes, once you get to big data inputs mine would be hundred times faster :P Yours would also be faster!

Comment: The real life arrays are around 1000 elements, yet with ranges ranging from 100 to 1000. So becomes quite big

Comment: @pr94 yeah I guess in those cases my answer should shine in speed

Comment: @U12-Forward If my understanding and timing test code is correct, Pandas actually loses out for the OP's case. See the bonus addition to [my timing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69072129/9769953).

Comment: This is actually doing the internal looping at least four times (repeat, add, groupby, cumcount) the amount required by explicit looping, plus changing the container type back and forth, which both require an extra looping over the whole memory. Additionally, some of the operations cannot be done in place, and hence do require extra memory allocation. Overall it is not straightforward that this would easily win over explicit looping.In fact, it seems that the opposite is true.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> np.hstack([np.arange(start, start+size) for start, size in zip(a, ranges)])
array([10, 11,  9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14])
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked about timing, so I compared the times of the three solutions (so far) in a very simple manner, using the `%timeit` magic function in Jupyter notebook cells.

I set it up as follows:

```
N = 1
a = np.array([10,9,12])
a = np.tile(a, N)
ranges = np.array([2,4,3])
ranges = np.tile(ranges, N)
a.shape, ranges.shape
```

So I could easily scale (albeit things not random, but repeated).

Then I ran:

```
%timeit np.hstack([np.arange(start, start+size) for start, size in zip(a, ranges)])
```

,

```
%timeit x = pd.Series(np.repeat(a, ranges)); x.add(x.groupby(x).cumcount()).to_numpy()
```

and

```
%timeit np.array([i for j in range(len(a)) for i in range(a[j],a[j]+ranges[j])])
```

---

Results are as follows:
N = 1:

1. 9.81 µs ± 481 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2. 568 µs ± 20.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3. 3.53 µs ± 81.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

N = 10:

1. 63.4 µs ± 976 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
2. 575 µs ± 15.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3. 25.1 µs ± 698 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

N = 100:

1. 612 µs ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2. 608 µs ± 25.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3. 237 µs ± 9.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

N = 1000:

1. 6.09 ms ± 52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2. 852 µs ± 2.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
3. 2.44 ms ± 43.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

So the Pandas solution wins when things get to arrays of 1000 elements or more, but the Python double list comprehension does an excellent job until that point. `np.hstack` probably loses out because of extra memory allocation and copying, but that's a guess. Note also that the Pandas solution is nearly the same time for each array size.

Caveats still exists because there are repeated numbers, and all values are relatively small integers. This really shouldn't matter, but I'm not (yet) betting on it. (For example, Pandas groupby functionality may be fast because of the repeated numbers.)

---

Bonus: the OP has statement in a comment that "The real life arrays are around 1000 elements, yet with ranges ranging from 100 to 1000. So becomes quite big – pr94".
So I adjusted my timing test to the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 1000
a = np.random.randint(100, 1000, N)
# This is how I understand "ranges ranging from 100 to 1000"
ranges = np.random.randint(100, 1000, N)

%timeit np.hstack([np.arange(start, start+size) for start, size in zip(a, ranges)])
%timeit  x = pd.Series(np.repeat(a, ranges)); x.add(x.groupby(x).cumcount()).to_numpy()
%timeit np.array([i for j in range(len(a)) for i in range(a[j],a[j]+ranges[j])])
```

Which comes out as :

- hstack: 2.78 ms ± 38.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- pandas: 18.4 ms ± 663 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- double list comprehension: 64.1 ms ± 427 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Which shows that those caveats I mentioned, in some form at least, do seem to exist. But people should double check whether this testing code is actually the most relevant and appropriate, and whether it is correct.

Comment: @pr94 That is up to you, and really depends what you prefer: introducing another dependency (Pandas, although you may already be using it), readability (I have to read the Pandas solution several times to understand it; `np.hstack` with `np.arange` is very straightforward to read) or just plain speed. Also, speed hardly means anything if this part of your code is a few percent of less in time compared to the overall code.

Comment: You're absolutely right that a list comprehension is more readable

Comment: Updated with `%timeit`, so better timings (I hope).

Comment: @pr94 this is not correct you say I select `pandas` better is you say base on your work decision to select which solution if your array is short you can see different runtime that `list` is best and when your array is big you need `pandas` and is better.

Comment: @user1740577 I have a hard time understanding your comment, but it seems to be about the fact that the best solution depends on the size. There is, however, a comment (sadly not in the question itself) from the OP staing their arrays are 1000s of elements, with ranges ranging from 100 to 1000 ("The real life arrays are around 1000 elements, yet with ranges ranging from 100 to 1000. So becomes quite big – 
pr94"). This is  why I went with increasing numbers up to 1000 elements.

Comment: @user1740577 I'm also *not* saying the Pandas solution is better; I'm saying it wins when arrays get large. I'm even pointing out the double list comprehension does an excellent job before that.

Comment: @9769953 thanks dude. yes I say that. thanks for your advice.

Comment: My original question also asked for a vectorized approach

Comment: @pr94 Please check the bonus addition to my timing answer. Things may not be as they seem.

Comment: @pr94 But why the vectorized approach? Because it reads cleaner, because you think it is faster, or something else?

Comment: Well at first I actually assumed that there must be a numpy function equivalent to ```np.repeat``` but then tailored toward this problem. So this was actually what my question aimed at finding out

Comment: But right now, on second glance, you may actually be right that list comprehension predominates for my very specific problem

Comment: @pr94 The reason I think a standard solution (function) does not exist, is that the arrays that you want to concatenate, are of different sizes: for `np.repeat` and `np.tile`, the factor is constant, not continuously varying. The varying sizes make it hard to properly vectorize this in the first place.

Comment: Eh, which list comprehension? There are two answers that use a list comprehension.

Comment: But overall, you should simply test yourself: you have the exact data (or better examples than I can generate), and you have all testing code examples here, so it's quick enough to do so. If you do, please let us know what your results are.

Comment: A Numba-based approach should be crushing those numbers anytime https://stackoverflow.com/a/69076670/5218354

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably going to be solved much faster with a Numba-compiled function:

```
@nb.jit 
def expand_range(values, counts): 
    n = len(values) 
    m = np.sum(counts) 
    r = np.zeros((m,), dtype=values.dtype) 
    k = 0 
    for i in range(n): 
        x = values[i] 
        for j in range(counts[i]): 
            r[k] = x + j 
            k += 1 
    return r
```

On the very small inputs:

```
%timeit expand_range(a, ranges)                                                                                                                                                
# 1.16 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit x = pd.Series(np.repeat(a, ranges)); x.add(x.groupby(x).cumcount()).to_numpy()                                                                                         
# 617 µs ± 4.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.hstack([np.arange(start, start+size) for start, size in zip(a, ranges)])                                                                                            
# 25 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.array([i for j in range(len(a)) for i in range(a[j],a[j]+ranges[j])])                                                                                               
# 13.5 µs ± 929 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and on somewhat larger inputs:

```
b = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000)
b_ranges = np.random.randint(1, 10, 1000)

%timeit expand_range(b, b_ranges)                                                                                                                                              
# 5.07 µs ± 98.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit x = pd.Series(np.repeat(a, ranges)); x.add(x.groupby(x).cumcount()).to_numpy()                                                                                         
# 617 µs ± 4.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.hstack([np.arange(start, start+size) for start, size in zip(a, ranges)])                                                                                            
# 25 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.array([i for j in range(len(a)) for i in range(a[j],a[j]+ranges[j])])                                                                                               
# 13.5 µs ± 929 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

these show that with Numba-based approach winning the speed gain is at least 100x over any of the other approaches proposed so far.

---

With the numbers closer to what as been indicated in one of the comments by the OP:

```
b = np.random.randint(10, 1000, 1000)
b_ranges = np.random.randint(100, 1000, 1000)

%timeit expand_range(b, b_ranges)                                                                                                                                              
# 1.5 ms ± 67.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000

%timeit x = pd.Series(np.repeat(b, b_ranges)); x.add(x.groupby(x).cumcount()).to_numpy()                                                                                       
# 91.8 ms ± 6.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.hstack([np.arange(start, start+size) for start, size in zip(b, b_ranges)])                                                                                          
# 10.7 ms ± 402 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.array([i for j in range(len(b)) for i in range(b[j],b[j]+b_ranges[j])])                                                                                             
# 144 ms ± 4.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

which is still at least a respectable 7x over the others.